# Creating remote interface of a Stateless EJB 2.1 bean and storing it in HTTP session for each user?

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, ejb, httpsession, stateless-session-bean

I am working on an enterprise application (EJB 2.1). In this app, whenever a user login, it is creating remote interface of a Stateless Session Bean and storing it in Session as an attribute.

This is the pseudo code:

```
HttpSession httpSession = null; // user's session
MyEjb myEjb = null; // Remote interface of EJB


// get session of the user
httpSession = ...;

// create remote interface of EJB
myEjb = ...;

// store remote interface of EJB in Session as an attribute
httpSession.setAttribute("MyEjb", myEjb);
```

Then for each EJB call it first gets the remote interface from the Session and then use it.

```
HttpSession httpSession = null; // user's session
MyEjb myEjb = null; // Remote interface of EJB


// get session of the user
httpSession = ...;

// get remote interface of EJB from session 
myEjb = (MyEjb) httpSession.getAttribute("MyEjb");

// use the EJB
```

What are the pros of cons of using this approach? Does it make sense?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: I am not doing this. This is an existing application and the programmers who code this way are not with this company anymore. I am trying to figure out the reasons of why they do it this way.

Comment: I can't see any reason why this would be necessary (or even useful): SLSBs are pooled at startup (so no performance gains to be had by clinging to a specific instance) and handed out by the container on request by a client - hanging on to a specific instance at best means that you're bloating the size of your sessions; at worst, you're causing the container to instantiate more beans to satisfy other clients/sessions.